# AEM 6.1 - can not see change after editing dialog.xm for Classic and touchUI

Tags: caching, dialog, refresh, aem

I'm editing dialog.xml files for classic and touchIU and I have a problem with getting my edits on the page. I'm using Brackets with AEM extension to export files to my local instance of AME. Any idea why this is happening ? I'm clearing cache every time.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the updated dialog actually made it to your AEM instance? If you can't see the same content in CRXDE as in your dialog.xml, something is wrong with the export.

Comment: Also try directly installing your view package using CRX/DE.